# Using CRM WebAPI to execute GetAllTimeZonesWithDisplayName function

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-365

I'm trying to execute the `GetAllTimeZonesWithDisplayName` function to retrieve the current user's timezone; however I'm having some difficulties

I've been following this [blog](https://xrmcenter.wordpress.com/2016/05/19/getting-timezone-with-microsoft-crm-web-api-2016/) but something seems to have changed. According to the author I should be able to go:

```
/api/data/v8.2/GetAllTimeZonesWithDisplayName(LocaleId=1033)
```

but this results in an error like:

```
{   
  "error":
  {
    "code":"",
    "message":"Resource not found for the segment 'GetAllTimeZonesWithDisplayName'.",
    "innererror":{
      "message":"Resource not found for the segment 'GetAllTimeZonesWithDisplayName'.",
      "type":"Microsoft.OData.Core.UriParser.ODataUnrecognizedPathException"
      ,"stacktrace":...
    }
  } 
}
```

So I had a look in the metadata (`/api/data/v8.2/$metadata`) and I can see that this method requires two parameters (I think)

```
<Function Name="GetAllTimeZonesWithDisplayName" IsBound="true">
  <Parameter Name="entityset" Type="Collection(mscrm.timezonedefinition)" Nullable="false"/> 
  <Parameter Name="LocaleId" Type="Edm.Int32" Nullable="false"/> 
  <ReturnType Type="Collection(mscrm.crmbaseentity)" Nullable="false"/> 
</Function>
```

But I don't know what is required for the `entityset` parameter and it doesn't seem to be listed in the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt593004.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function, according to a metadata, is bound to an entityset `Parameter Name="entityset" Type="Collection(mscrm.timezonedefinition)" Nullable="false"/>` means you should start it from the set. And, I don't know why, usage of bound functions requires full function name so the result will be:

`/api/data/v8.2/timezonedefinitions/Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.GetAllTimeZonesWithDisplayName(LocaleId=1033)`

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean when you say "you should start it from the set" can you elaborate a little more?

Comment: Oh, I understand: `/api/data/v8.2/TIMEZONEDEFININITIONS/Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.GetAllTimeZonesWithDisplayName(LocaleId=1033)`

Comment: Correct, Exactly the URL I've posted in the answer

Comment: yep, when I initially read your answer I didn't notice the difference. Thanks again!